NGINX add header to only text/html files when using try_files
Does anyone know how with the following location block in nginx:
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

How can I add a header to only text/html files instead of everything? As i cant figure out how to put a check/if statment on it just for the text/html files.

If all of your text/html files match the filename ending with .html, you could identify them using a regular expression location.
For example:
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
location ~* \.html$ {
    add_header ...;
}

